# Derivation of dual vector component transformation. Wald's book

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm working through the second chapter of *General Relativity* by Robert Wald, and I'm getting stuck on something that should be simple, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Wald writes that the transformation law for the components of a dual vector is

$$\omega'_{\mu'} = \omega_\mu \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^{\mu'}},\tag{2.3.7}$$
with summation over repeated indices. No surprises there, but he claims that this follows from only the corresponding transformation law for vectors,

$$v'^{\mu'} = v^\mu \frac{\partial x'^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\mu},\tag{2.3.6}$$

and the definition of the dual basis,

$$e^{\mu}(e_\nu) = \delta_\nu^{\mu}.\tag{2.3.1}$$

It is when I try to verify this that I run into trouble. Let us use *coordinate bases* with the conventional notations $\partial_\mu$ and $dx^\mu$. My attempt starts by using (2.3.1) to write

$$\omega'_{\mu'} = \omega'_{\nu'} \delta_{\mu'}^{\nu'} = \omega'_{\nu'} dx'^{\nu'}(\partial'_{\mu'}) = \omega'_{\nu'} dx'^{\nu'}(\delta_{\mu'}^{\rho'} \partial'_{\rho'}).\tag{2}$$

Then, for fixed $\mu'$ thinking of the $\delta_{\mu'}^{\rho'}$ as the components of the vector $\partial'_{\mu'}$, I use (2.3.6) to write

$$\delta_{\mu'}^{\rho'} \partial'_{\rho'} = \delta_{\mu'}^{\rho'} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^{\rho'}} \partial_{\rho} = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^{\mu'}} \partial_{\rho},\tag{3}$$

and hence, using the linearity of the action of the dual vector, I get

$$\omega'_{\mu'} = \omega'_{\nu'} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^{\mu'}} dx'^{\nu'}(\partial_{\rho}).\tag{4}$$

But I still cannot resolve $dx'^{\nu'}(\partial_{\rho})$ into anything useful, so this is where I am stuck.

It feels like I am close. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, I think I've got it! I can simply write $\omega'_{\nu'} dx'^{\nu'}$ in the unprimed basis of $V^*$,

$$\omega'_{\nu'} dx'^{\nu'} = \omega_\mu dx^\mu.$$

Then equation (4) becomes

$$\omega'_{\mu'} = \omega_{\mu} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^{\mu'}} dx^{\mu}(\partial_\rho) = \omega_{\mu} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^{\mu'}} \delta_\rho^\mu = \omega_{\mu} \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^{\mu'}},$$

and we are done!

Still, I would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable would take a look to see if my derivation (including the steps in the question) is correct. Is there a simpler way to do it, while still only using (2.3.1) and (2.3.6)?